# d3.js - display time on xAxis

Tags: datetime, d3.js, axis, timeline

I'm doing something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2338034). I adopted this example.

But I want to have an x-axis that shows dates, not just some numbers as in the example. Here is the important part of my code: but it is not working. Did I miss something to change?

```
var lanes = ["lane1","lane2"],
        laneLength = lanes.length,
        items = [{"lane": 0, "id": "before", "start": "2012-04-23 18:25:43", "end": "2012-05-23 18:25:43"},
                {"lane": 0, "id": "crossing", "start": "2012-04-23 18:25:43", "end": "2012-05-23 18:25:43"},
                {"lane": 0, "id": "after", "start": "2012-04-23 18:25:43", "end": "2012-05-23 18:25:43"},
                {"lane": 1, "id": "before", "start": "2012-04-23 18:25:43", "end": "2012-05-23 18:25:43"},
                {"lane": 1, "id": "crossing", "start": "2012-04-23 18:25:43", "end": "2012-05-23 18:25:43"},
                {"lane": 1, "id": "after", "start": "2012-04-23 18:25:43", "end": "2012-05-23 18:25:43"}]
        timeBegin = "2012-04-23 18:25:43",
        timeEnd = "2012-05-23 18:25:43";



        //scales
        var x = d3.time.scale()
                .domain([timeBegin, timeEnd])
                .range([0, w]);
        var x1 = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, w]);


           //xAxis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("top");


        chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axisTime")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + m[0]) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: You need to parse the dates. See e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).

Comment: I've updated it now: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/U4cs7/) but it is still not working!

Comment: You need to set the domains properly to the correct range. And your calculation of the width of the rectangles was incorrect: http://jsfiddle.net/U4cs7/1/